# Why do I get files downloaded with %20 instead of spaces?

Tags: windows-7, macos, osx-lion, encoding

I need to download the notes from the school website, it is a easy task. But the file I downloaded always get a ugly filename on OS X, such as 
**D1.5%20-%20Software%20testing%20strategies**, it should be **D1.5 - Software testing strategies** originally. How can I solve this problem?

I have already looked at the `iconv` command, but it only changes the encoding of the file's content but not the encoding of the filename.

Comment: The %20's ( 20 hex, or decimal 32) is the ASCII code for white space. I suspect it is more a browser problem than a OS X problem.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to fix the filenames and replace `%20` with a single space, open up a Terminal, navigate to the folder in question, and run:

```
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f//%20/ }"; done
```

The real issue would be the browser not saving the file correctly – try a different browser to see if that's really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the %20 is an unicode equivalent of the whitespace.

Have you tried renaming the file via the file browser or the terminal after you downloaded it?